# Genymotion device boots up and disappears after showing a black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, genymotion

I am currently facing this problem where my Genymotion device boots up, displays a black screen and disappears after 4-5 seconds.
I am using Genymotion v2.4.0 on a remote Ubuntu 12.04 server with X11 forwarding enabled (the device window is displayed on my local MacBook pro).

Whenever I try to boot up my Genymotion device, it throws up lot of OpenGl related error messages on the command line.

```
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
Unknown TCPCLI command 1003
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:370 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1246 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1269 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:370 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1246 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1269 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:173 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:173 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindAttribLocation:197 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindAttribLocation:197 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glLinkProgram:1593 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1170 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1170 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1170 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:556 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:556 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:370 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1246 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1269 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:370 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1246 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1269 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:173 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:173 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindAttribLocation:197 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindAttribLocation:197 error 0x501

sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glLinkProgram:1593 error 0x501
    sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1170 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1170 error 0x501
sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1170 error 0x501
 sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:556 error 0x501
 sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:55     6 error 0x501
  eglMakeCurrent failed
 eglMakeCurrent failed
FrameBuffer::post eglMakeCurrent failed
zsh: segmentation fault  /data/work/genymotion/player --vm-name 3e01db2b-798a-    4cc3-8f51-55cbfa64bb0d
```

This error started appearing all of a sudden since the past 2 days, before which the Genymotion devices used to boot up normally on my remote server.
My guess is some f the OpenGL drivers may have gone bad or something but not quite sure how I can go about fixing this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to start a device on your server (without X forwarding)? Is it working?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar error but not show error only

```
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
Unknown TCPCLI command 1003
```

it crash and disappear and the VM remain on

genymotion version 2.4.0

thanks
Emiliano

Answer (score 0):

I solved the black screen problem some weeks ago just by updating genymotion and virtual box and renewing the network config in vbox: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/genymotion-users/network/genymotion-users/QAX_UrAzEn0/o947IXpsDuIJ

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've already tried updating both genymotion and Virtual box to latest versions, but still doesn't work. Tried updating the Host-Only network settings as well in the VirtualBox but doesn't solve this issue. I am currently using Genymotion v2.4 and VirtualBox v4.3.24